# Audio output missing samples: bug or misconfigured? (Ubuntu Studio 18.04, snd_usb_audio)

Tags: 18.04, usb, sound, alsa, ubuntu-studio

I'm using a Audient id44 digital audio interface, connected by USB.  I see distortion -- missing samples -- in the output.  To debug it I output digitally generated sine wave at CD resolution (with `aplay`) and looked at the output signal on an oscilloscope.  The audio interface is intended for studio work and the Ubuntu is Ubuntu Studio 18.04, which should be optimised for latency etc.

**My question: does this look like a bug or does it look like something is misconfigured?**

Output is 440 Hz sine wave, which has a period of 2.27 ms, and we see that about 0.62 ms is just missing.
[image]

## Environment

- Ubuntu Studio https://ubuntustudio.org/tour/audio/
- Ubuntu 18.04.4, freshly rebooted

  - Ubuntu Studio says it's not LTS https://ubuntustudio.org/2019/04/ubuntu-studio-18-04-extended-support/
  - Files are nevertheless labelled LTS `/.disk/info` says `Ubuntu-Studio 18.04 LTS "Bionic Beaver" - Release i386 (20180426)` and `/etc/os_release` says `PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS"`
- Kernel release: 4.15.0-111-lowlatency
- Architecture: i686
- Computer: Intel DG43GT motherboard with 8 GByte RAM
- CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU E7600 @ 3.06GHz (family: 0x6, model: 0x17, stepping: 0xa)
- ALSA Driver version: k4.15.0-111-lowlatency
- ALSA Library version: 1.1.3
- ALSA sound card description USB-Audio - Audient iD44, Audient Audient iD44 at usb-0000:00:1a.7-6, high speed

## Things ruled out

- It's not the particular id44: The error does not happen with same hardware plugged into a Windows 10 Dell 780 computer
- It's not the audio file: Tried lots of different audio files.
- It's not the output rate: Tried lots of 44.1 kHz, 48 kHz etc.
- It's not the analogue side: couldn't explain scope image.
- It's not the USB socket: It makes no difference what USB port is used.
- It's not the higher-level sound program: makes no difference whether you use aplay, VLC, or ardour
- It's not this particular computer: The error does appear with a stock Ubuntu 18.04 laptop

Comment: FYI: Ubuntu Studio was **not** a LTS release, have you enabled the Ubuntu Studio PPA to get *extended* support, as standard packages stopped being supported after 9 months for 18.04 (due to it not being a LTS release).  I don't know if this is your issue; just checking - https://ubuntustudio.org/2019/04/ubuntu-studio-18-04-extended-support/

Comment: @guiverc thanks for that.  Very interesting comment about LTS: I'd written LTS because that's what the files in the system say, certainly your linked note is pretty clear that it isn't.  I've edited my question to add your link.  Certainly I'll try the PPA when I'm next at the studio.

Comment: There's a nice guide about professional audio setup in the [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Professional_audio) which is applicable to ubuntu too.That might help you.

Comment: FYI: The Ubuntu base is supported for 5 years (for any flavor),however standard flavors have 3 years of support (if they are LTS, Ubuntu Studio wasn't).  The Ubuntu Studio however provide *extended support* via the use of a PPA bring the 18.04 to the same length as other Ubuntu flavors. It's needed for Ubuntu Studio applications/features. You can use `ubuntu-security-status` to check for your actual system (though I'm not sure it handles PPA's very well, and *extended* support for Ubuntu Studio is now via PPA on 18.04)